# Firebase custom auth in server-to-server scenario

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I need to implement a scenario where, after a file is uploaded to Google Cloud Storage, a function is triggered and processes the file. In this case, processing basically means sanitizing the file, storing it into Firestore and making it accessible via another HTTP-triggered function (a REST API of sorts).

Both user-facing ends of this process (a file upload and HTTP function) need to be secured. The process will be used in server-to-server scenario: one side is going to be a backend written in either Node.js or .NET, the other will be my Firebase solution (Cloud Storage and HTTP-triggered function as per above). In Firebase, I am going to maintain a custom set of users that should have access to the system - my idea was to use a simple system where each user will have a client id and a client secret (basically an oAuth client credentials grant type).

Based on what I read online, an only option to implement this is to use [Firebase auth with custom tokens][1]. I found lots of examples online on how to do that, but it was always about client-to-server scenarios (e.g. a Javascript web app talking to REST API). Server-to-server scenarios were not mentioned anywhere and indeed, I am unsure how to go about implementing it - I can call   `auth.createCustomToken(uid)` just fine in my HTTP Firestore function, but there seem to be no server-side libraries I could use to call `auth.SignInWithCustomTokenAsync(customToken)`.

To sum it up:

1. How can I use Firebase auth with custom tokens in server-to-server
   scenario, where I need to sign in using a previously generated
   custom token from a server environment?
2. If it is not possible,
   what's the other alternative to securely implement the
   above-described architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Google Support and if anyone else is struggling with this, in server-side scenarios, recommended approach is to call [signInWithCustomToken endpoint in Firebase Auth REST API.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-custom-token)